# Create VBScript or batch file to call command line and terminate once done

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd, ping

I'm really inexperienced when it comes to VBScript but here is what I want to do and I hope you can help.

I'm using Windows 7 x64 bit and I want to open cmd and ping a site 20 times after that I want to terminate the command line and save the ping log to a text file.

I need help with this.

My ultimate goal however is to be able to ping 3 different sites 20 times each and log it all in 1 text file.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just use a batch file for this. You don't need VBS for it. Look at cmd with /c option: http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html. Or just write a batch file that calls `ping host /n 20`.

Comment: Just try from this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997034/ping-script-with-loop-and-save-in-a-txt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997034/ping-script-with-loop-and-save-in-a-txt)

Answer (score 2):

Just write a batch file for this. The following batch script pings 3 hosts 20 times each in succession and pipes the output both OUT and ERR to output.log (you can amend the hosts to any number of hosts you wish. You can also amend the ping count and output file):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set PING_HOSTS=host1;host2;host3
set PING_COUNT=20
set OUT_LOG=output.log

if exist %OUT_LOG% del %OUT_LOG%
for %%f in (%PING_HOSTS%) do (
    echo Pinging %%f...
    ping %%f /n %PING_COUNT% 1>> %OUT_LOG% 2>>&1
)

echo Process complete.
@echo on
```

Or, you can use `cmd /c "ping host /n 20 1> output.log 2>&1"` instead.

Any of the above can be called from VBS, but there's entirely no need for VBS here.